# ERROR ITMS-9000 App Store must be built with public (GM) versions of Xcode 5.1.1 when submitting IPA using Application Loader

Tags: xcode, air, adobe, itunes

I have an app compiled using Adobe Flash builder with AIR 4.0 SDK that generates the error below whenever I use the Application Loader to submit the IPA file to iTunes Connect.

> **ERROR ITMS-9000:** This bundle is invalid. New apps and app updates
>   submitted to the App Store must be built with public (GM) versions of
>   Xcode 5.1.1 or higher and iOS 7 SDK when submitting IPA file compiled
>   from flash builder with AIR 4.0 sdk. Do not submit apps built with
>   beta software. ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by upgrading to Air 14 (http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/air.html) and Flash CC. Hope this works for you too!